# compile with -ansi -pedantic -Wall switches automatically with gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

We are required to compile C source codes using gcc in this manner:

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall program.c
```

I'm wondering how can I 'automate' this so when I enter:

```
gcc program.c
```

It will automatically compile with the 3 switches. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the implicit rules of make, so that you don't have to write a makefile for every program. Make will automatically call the compiler if you say `make foo` and there exists a `foo.c` file in the current directory. To add flags to this define the variable `CFLAGS` in your environment, e.g. in bash add `export CFLAGS="-Wall -pedantic -ansi"` to `.bashrc`.

If your program depends on multiple files however you'll have to create a makefile, but for C compilation you can get away with just listing dependancies so long as one of them has the same base name as a target.

For example for this makefile:

```
# Makefile
foo:foo.o bar.o
```

running `make` will execute the commands

```
gcc $CFLAGS -c -o foo.o foo.c
gcc $CFLAGS -c -o bar.o bar.c
gcc -o foo foo.o bar.o
```

without you having to add any rules.

Answer (score 8):

To automate the build of any number of build steps / complex parameters, you should use a [makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)).

Once you have a makefile you simply need to type: `make`

Comment: Downvoted for proposing a hardcoded (and broken) Makefile when the implicit rules with `export CFLAGS=...` in the environment does precisely what Jef Ty wants.  (See Scott Wales' answer).

Comment: @Matt B: The purpose of the makefile was simply to introduce the concept of a makefile while giving the most simple possible example that will work by typing make.   Without using implicit rules.   I removed the example though.  It is very possible that the OP will want to do something more complex with his makefile if not today then soon.

Answer (score 3):

```
alias gcc="gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall"
```

But as @Brian said, you really should use a makefile, or better, a build system like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) or [SCons](http://www.scons.org).

Comment: I would call it something besides `gcc` so that if I ever wanted to use it in non-crazy-naggy mode I could still call `gcc`.

Comment: @nategoose: If you want to call "plain" gcc without invoking the alias, you would put a backslash in front of the command \gcc to prevent alias substitution.

Answer (score 2):

A makefile would be the traditional way, especially as part of a larger build process.

If you frequently want to build without a makefile, you could define an alias in your `.bashrc` or equivalent: `alias gcc=gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell script that takes some cues by how its called and invokes `make` after setting `CFLAGS` appropriately for the occasional one-off build.

Lets say you have `/usr/bin/compile` , which is a shell script that looks at `$0` to see what name actually invoked it. You then make symbolic links to it named `pedantic`, `fullwarn`, etc.

In the shell script itself, something like:

```
OLDCFLAGS=$CFLAGS
WHATAMI=$(basename $0)

case "$WHATAMI" in
    pedantic)
        export CFLAGS="-Wall -pedantic -ansi"
        make $@
        exit $?
    ;;
    c99)
        export CFLAGS="-std=c99 ... ... ..."
        ....
```

Then, to compile foo.c with the extra naggy flags:

`pedantic foo`

This is handy, as I said for one-off builds, e.g trying to compile code that someone posted in a question, or working out how to use a new library, etc.

For anything else, just use a makefile, as others have said.